# Когда ручной вызов GC.Collect() оправдан?

Tags: c#, .net, сборщик-мусора

Часто нахожу в коде вызовы `GC.Collect()`, например при работе с графиков через GDI+.

В умных книжках пишут, что его никогда не нужно вызывать самому.

Собственно вопрос, а есть ли оправданные случаи, когда его нужно вызывать или это признак плохого когда?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Обычно не нужно. Иногда имеет смысл это делать:

1. После уничтожения большого количества объектов (например, закрытия формы с большим количеством элементов)
2. Когда приложение имеет четко выраженные периоды активности и простоя. Если принудительно вызвать сборку мусора в период простоя, уменьшится вероятность того, что она произойдет в период активности и затормозит выполнение кода.

Ссылки:

[When to call GC.Collect()](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2004/11/29/when-to-call-gc-collect/)

[When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect)

Comment: Под большим количеством объектов понимается ведь, объекты, уничтожение которых предположительно высвободят много памяти? А то например массив из 1000 упакованных интов в Object весит мелочь, НО объектов много.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Скорее всего да, имеет значение главным образом объем памяти, а не количество объектов. Хотя массивы из большого числа упакованных в object маленьких структур тоже могут занимать много памяти, ведь на каждый объект выделяется какой-то служебный блок.

Answer (score 3):

Просто так, без веских причин, и без точного понимания, что происходит при сборке мусора, дергать `GC.Collect` не стоит. Рантайм сам вполне справляется с автоматической сборкой мусора.

Не стоит дергать `Collect` ни по таймеру, ни "на всякий случай" - это не даст никакого  реального "ускорения" или улучшения.

Более-менее реальные причины для вызова `Collect`:

- Вы точно знаете что в вашем приложении только что стало мусором *огромное* количество объектов И при этом мгновенно сократить потребление памяти приложением достаточно критично. Если мгновенность не требуется (а она не требуется почти никогда) - хватит автосборки.
- В рамках теста, который меряет потребление памяти.
- В рамках теста, который проверяет работу кода с WeakReference.
- При входе / выходе из режима `GCLatencyMode.LowLatency` и `GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency` - стоит вызвать `GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced)`
- (возможно) при выходе из региона `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` / `GC.EndNoGCRegion`.

Топик на enSO: [When is it acceptable to call GC.Collect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478167/when-is-it-acceptable-to-call-gc-collect)